# Sorting output over multiple lines Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, for-loop

I have following output, with each number being on their own line.

```
reaction  2 
reaction  1 
reaction  1 
reaction  2 
reaction  3
```

How can I sort the numbers in this output to descend from the biggest to the smallest value

```
reaction  3 
reaction  2 
reaction  2 
reaction  1 
reaction  1
```

I got this output with this code. Its a script for a discord bot, that get all messages that have a reaction, checks if its the reaction you were looking for (`msgSplit[1]`) and checks if its has the amount of reactions you were looking for with `if num >= int(msgSplit[2]):`

```py
async for historical_message in message.channel.history(limit=historyLimit):
    for reaction in historical_message.reactions:
        if reaction.emoji == msgSplit[1]:
            num = reaction.count
            if num >= int(msgSplit[2]):
                print(reaction, num)
```

Comment: I can't really show it nor see it properly, I only know that if i print the reaction and num, i get outputs across multiple lines. For example one line is  1 the second output is  2, the third might be  1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you store the output on the list as a list of tuples and sort the output in descending order.

```
output = [] # create empty list
for reaction in historical_message.reactions:
    if reaction.emoji == msgSplit[1]:
        num = reaction.count
        if num >= int(msgSplit[2]):
            # append the the output to the list as tuple
            output.append((reaction, num))
            

print(sorted(output, reverse=True))
```

Comment: weirdly the outputs remains the same...
[1]
[2]
[2]
[1]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[1]

Answer (score 0):

There most sensible solution is to save them to a list and then sort the list, but not all sorting algorithms are made equally. If time efficiency is not really an issue and it just has to give the desired output then "bubble sort" is probably the easiest and most intuitive to implement, but its time complexity is O(n^2) which is bad.

"Heapsort" ensures the result will be O(nlogn) in time and O(1) in time which is nice.

See this cheat sheet to decide what is most appropriate for your purposes: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sorting+algorithms+cheat+sheet&t=brave&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn-images-1.medium.com%2Fmax%2F2000%2F1*Ggl_e8v-IzxUdienwrTMZQ.png

Comment: so do i just create an empty list, append the num to it and run and let the for example the bubblesort sort it?

Comment: That is what I would do, yes. It's probably not the only solution but it seems to me to be the most intuitive approach.

You could also insert the data in order, so rather than, for example, adding "5" to [3, 7] and getting [3, 7, 5] and having to sort it at the end, you could insert the 5 into the middle spot in the first place.

Comment: I tried combining your idea with the one from Dejene T. and somehow it doesnt output on the console nor is it sorted the way it should be. I used this code https://pastebin.com/0k2PasTi

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort list method in python and tell it to use the last "column" as the key to order.

```py
def last_col(line):
    return int(l.split()[-1])

text = """reaction  2 
reaction  1 
reaction  1 
reaction  2 
reaction  3
reaction  11
reaction  342384324"""

lines = text.split('\n')

lines.sort(reverse=True, key=last_col)

print(lines)
# ['reaction  342384324', 'reaction  11', 'reaction  3', 'reaction  2 ', 'reaction  2 ', 'reaction  1 ', 'reaction  1 ']
```